# Simplest way to create a submit button with html and js?

Tags: javascript

The main trouble with inputs is that you can't use either :before or :after. I have to match the CSS of my input buttons with other s  and it's almost impossible to do with just css.

I was thinking it would be a lot easier to use a simple  with an onclick="" attribute that functions as a submit button but I'm not sure if this is a good or bad idea. For example I was thinking a  used as an input might be perceived as something bad by SEO or browsers on the other hand I'm submitting forms with javascript every day.

Would using elements like  for submit buttons not be recommended?

Also how do I tell JS to submit the form around the div so I can create one snippet that works on all forms? Would this work?

```
<div onclick="this.submit()"></div>
```

Comment: What if you use `<button type="submit">Click</button>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also `<button type='submit'>Submit</button>`, I'm not sure whether that works with CSS `:before` and `:after`. You should look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) if you want to do more powerful things with JavaScript, it seems perfect for your situation here.

Comment: I'm really liking this solution. I had never heard about the button tag. Is it going to be deprecated or is not supported across al browsers? It seems a little redundant since it's the same as the `input type="submit"`

Comment: From W3schools: `Note: If you use the <button> element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use <input> to create buttons in an HTML form.` What is this suppose to mean?

Comment: W3Schools is inaccurate (see http://w3fools.com/). The `<button>` element is completely fine as long as you include the `type` attribute like I did there. The element is  not going to be deprecated, as it is included in HTML5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use jQuery, this does the trick with pure JS:

HTML:

```
<div onclick="submitButton(this)"></div>
```

script:

```
function submitButton (element) {
    while(element.parentElement !== document.body) {
        if (element.parentElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'form') {
            element.parentElement.submit();
            return;
        } else {
            element = element.parentElement;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<div onclick="document.myform.submit()"></div>
```

If your div is a child of the form element you can use

```
 <div onclick="this.parentNode.submit()"></div>
```

However, you could also use a framework like jQuery to handle the submit

```
$('#divId').onclick(function(){
    $('#formId').submit();
});
```

Comment: that would only work in a form with `name=myform` I believe I was asking if there was a way to make it work like submit buttons. (submit the form wrapping the element)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div onclick="document.forms[0].submit();"></div>
```

Comment: Will be exact answer for limited scenario. What if there are different forms?

Answer (score 1):

> > Also how do I tell JS to submit the form around the div so I can create one snippet that works on all forms? Would this work?

```
this.parentNode.submit();
```

The other stuff I don't know. You would like to not use JavaScript at all and only use css :before and :after to insert content but button and input or button type submit don't have those css properties?

Comment: yeah, I'd rather just use an input type="submit" but they don't have those properties only elements with opening and closing tags do

Comment: Not sure if there is such a thing as button type submit. They have opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery submit method could be useful to you:

```
$('element').onclick(function(){
$('form:first').submit();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/